# Bulk upload when field terminator is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Create table TEST
(
    Client_Code Varchar(255),
    Segment Varchar(255),
    Symbol Varchar(255),
    Instrument Varchar(255),
    Expiry Datetime,
    Strike_Price Numeric(18,8),
    Opt_Type Varchar(255),
    Buy_Qty Varchar(255),
    Buy_Value Varchar(255),
    Sell_Qty Varchar(255),
    Sell_Value Varchar(255),
    Product Varchar(255)
)

bulk insert TEST
from 'D:\Filewithdata.txt'
with (firstrow = 1,FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',rowterminator = '\n')

go
```

I am using above codes to bulk upload for attached files

Above code works fine when file has data (`Header plus data` showing in `row 1` and I am extracting `header` from `row 1 column:= Client_Code` )

But someday file could be blank and have only `header` in `row 1`

How to run this when file is blank?

Comment: What is the purpose of uploading a blank file ?

Comment: I know there is no Purpose. I will Put it on Job to Pick File, my purpose is how System will check that file is empty or not

Comment: Could u provide us with a sample of "Filewithdata.txt" ?

Answer (score -1):

```
Create table TEST
(
Client_Code Varchar(255),
Segment Varchar(255),
Symbol Varchar(255),
Instrument Varchar(255),
Expiry Datetime,
Strike_Price Numeric(18,8),
Opt_Type Varchar(255),
Buy_Qty Varchar(255),
Buy_Value Varchar(255),
Sell_Qty Varchar(255),
Sell_Value Varchar(255),
Product Varchar(255),
)

bulk insert TEST
from 'D:\Filewithdata.txt'
with (firstrow = 1,FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',rowterminator = '\n')
go
```

Comment: down-voting reason: copying the script from the question sector.

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and the question apart form the addition of an incorrect comma at the end of `Product Varchar(255),`? It looks like you've copied and pasted the code from the question and made it slightly wrong... am I missing something?